# I need to use a like query in mongo php

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I have used this query in shell. It worked fine. If I use it in php, it shows me an error

```
<?php
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->foo;
$collection = $db->base;
$query = array( "ro" => '/^a/' );
$cursor = $collection->find($query);

foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    echo $obj["ro"] . "<br/>";
}
```

I am not sure, will `db.base.find({"ro": /^a/}).limit(10);` query work in php??

Comment: What error? Whenever you say something like "shows me an error", it surely helps to actually post the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use MongoRegex() ...

See docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php

So the PHP code would be something like ...

```
$regex = new MongoRegex("/^a/"); 
$where = array('ro' => $regex);
$cursor = $collection->find($where);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use mongodb extension, you should use MongoDB\BSON\Regex() instead of MongoRegex()

```
$regex = new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^a"); 
$where = array('ro' => $regex);
$cursor = $collection->find($where)
```

You Don't have to use **"/" [regex] "/"**. Just the regex works fine

Answer (score -1):

In one line:

```
$mCollection->find(array("date" => new MongoRegex("/2011-10-25/")));
```